# How to prove that the number $\pi$ is irrational through differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can it be proved that $\pi$ is an irrational number through differential equations?

Comment: Well . . . . . . . . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm: Niven's proof of the irrationality of $\pi$ [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-53/issue-6/A-simple-proof-that-pi-is-irrational/bams/1183510788.full) contains a differential equation
$F''(x) + F(x) = f(x)$, although I don't know if you'd count it as a proof "through differential equations".